# Redirect Doesn't Draw the Component in Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect the user if s/he is not logged in yet. I am storing it in the `redux` state with `isLoggedIn` state and set it false unless user logged in.

In `routers` at `index.js`, I have set a condition to redirect user to `/login`, but it doesn't work. It does changes the url to `/login`, I can see `Layout` component is loaded but `Login` component is not loaded.

If I just remove the condition, I can see the `Login` component with `Route` component.

I have tried so many different things, yet I couldn't find a proper way to handle this problem. Hope you guys can help me. Btw, this is for learning, so I might have amateur code.

`Routes/index.js`

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, history) {
        super(props);
        this.store = this.props.store;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                {this.store.isLoggedIn ?
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={
                            (props) => <Home {...props} store={this.store} />
                        } />
                        <Route path="/quality" render={
                            (props) => <h1>Quality Track</h1>
                        } />
                        <Route path="/login" render={
                            (props) => <Login {...props} store={this.store} />
                        } />
                        <Route render={
                            (props) => <Login {...props} store={this.store} />
                        } />
                    </Switch>
                    :
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                }
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my `App` component where I use `Routes`.

```
  render() { 
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Routes store = {this.store} />
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

**EDIT**

When I changed the last part of Routes/index.js, it worked. Is it okay to use it this way?

```
            <div>
                <Redirect to="/login" />
                <Route path="/login" render={
                    (props) => <Login {...props} store={this.store} />
                } />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `Switch` block contains the routes available when `isLoggedIn` is `true`. The second block's routes are available otherwise. In the case `isLoggedIn` is `false` any URL will redirect to `/login`.

```
{this.store.isLoggedIn ?
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={
            (props) => <Home {...props} store={this.store} />
        } />
        <Route path="/quality" render={
            (props) => <h1>Quality Track</h1>
        } />
    </Switch>
    :
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" render={
            (props) => <Login {...props} store={this.store} />
        } />
        <Redirect to="/login" />
    </Switch>
}
```